# Airflow can't find main module after install

Tags: python, airflow

I just installed Python 3.10.11 on Suse SLES-15.4.
Python runs as expected:

```
~> python3 -c "import os, sys; print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))"
/usr/bin
~> pip3 --version
pip 22.0.4 from /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```

As I am not a fan of having an aplication installed in my personal home folder, so I defined the AIRFLOW_HOME to a directory which I created :

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=/usr/lib/airflow
```

Then, as written in the [quick start guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start.html), I defined the following variables:

```
AIRFLOW_VERSION=2.6.1
PYTHON_VERSION="$(python3 --version | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -d "." -f 1-2)"
CONSTRAINT_URL=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-${AIRFLOW_VERSION}/constraints-${PYTHON_VERSION}.txt
```

and then proceeded with install:

```
pip3 install -t $AIRFLOW_HOME "apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" --constraint "${CONSTRAINT_URL}"
```

I tried to configure the **/etc/profile.d/python.sh** to guess what could prevent Airflow from starting:

```
# add python startup script for interactive sessions
export PYTHONSTARTUP=/etc/pythonstart
export LC_ALL="fr_CH.UTF-8"
export AIRFLOW_HOME=/usr/lib/airflow
export PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/lib/airflow:/usr/lib/airflow/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/airflow:/usr/lib/airflow/bin/airflow:/usr/lib/python3.10:/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

But still, when I try to run Airflow at first, I receive an error message:

```
~> airflow standalone
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/airflow/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
    from airflow.__main__ import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow'
```

Do you have any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: Maybe you can try `python -m airflow standalone` in case it's because the main command of airflow it's not defined.

Comment: It returns /usr/bin/python3: No module named airflow

Comment: Then it seems airflow wasn't properly installed. Could execute `pip list | grep airflow` to see if airflow appears there with the proper version?

Comment: I tried  pip list | grep airflow and  pip3 list | grep airflow , it returns nothing ...

Comment: I answer you below because it could be the following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pip package is not getting installed in a place where it can be read.
To fix it you can add to the rest of exports in the file **/etc/profile.d/python.sh**:

```
# ...
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$AIRFLOW_HOME
```

Or you can try to install airflow without the flag: `-t $AIRFLOW_HOME` since it will be installed in the default PYTHONPATH assigned with the rest of pip packages.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the issue now : 1-Python was installed using Zypper with sudo. 2-PYTHONPATH was not defined. 3-I installed Airflow with my user instead of sudo, so it could not be written in the default location: /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages. Since I now defined the PYTHONPATH, it works as expected.